# How can I retrieve all row of one column in firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a firebase database call to retrieve all row of one particular column in the firebase database of my app and display it in a textbox in my flutter app.

That is, to retrieve all phone numbers in the Users table.

For instance, in SQL we can do like this:

```
SELECT (PhoneNumers) FROM Users
```

I am new in flutter/dart, I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

Its really easy.
First of all, setup and initialize firebase in you project. Then make a function and create an instance of firestore like this

```
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
```

Then make something called Collection reference:

```
 CollectionReference users = await firestore.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
   print(doc["PhoneNumber"].toString())
});
```

This will grab every collection from Users, loop over them and then print out the document PhoneNumber to console. There is no way to just get a single document field from firestore. It might seem weird, but its quite useful at times. Right now, you have access to every document field of every user of your app.

Comment: Did it help?   iam curiois